# How to apply substring to every letter in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an array of textstrings like this:

```
phone = $(data).find('.tel a')
```

I would like to apply a substring(8) to every item in the array called phone. Is a for-loop the best way to do it?

Comment: Apply what to what now ?

Comment: What array are you talking about?

Comment: Technically, that's an array-like jQuery object, not a true array.

Comment: Although it's array-like, the elements of the array are DOM elements, not strings, so applying substring to them still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Like `$(data).find(".tel a").map(function (i, el) { return $(el).text().substring(8); }).get();`? This would return an array of strings that contain each matched `<a>`'s **inner text**, but `.substring(8)` applied

Comment: Please clarify your question. We don't know what you mean by "apply a substring". Perhaps you want to *extract* a substring from the *contents* of the jQuery object?

Comment: The "array of textstrings" is the baffling part, because you're assigning a collection of jQuery objects (HTML elements) to the variable. Could you show an example of the HTML structure, and what it should look like after the operation?

Comment: @Ian Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it. It's obviously what the OP is looking for, and everyone else is being deliberately obtuse, taking advantage of the OP's poor language skills.

Comment: @Barmar That's obviously not the case. Or were you also deliberately obtuse with your previous comments?

Comment: @Juhana Ian's answer uses `.text()` to address the issue I pointed out earlier.

Comment: Why did this question get so many downvotes?  It's a good question, well formatted, makes sense.  He wants to map a substring to an array. +1 on principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phone`, as it stands, contains a jQuery object, which is an Array-like Object of DOM elements. If you want to iterate over all of them and get their **inner text**, applying `.substring(8)` to each, and building an array out of them, you can use something like this:

```
var phoneArray = $(data).find(".tel a").map(function (i, el) {
    return $(el).text().substring(8);
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/96HWv/

(in the demo, I had to emulate what `data` could be, although I'm guessing it is an HTML string in your real code)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the map() method :

```
phone = phone.get().map(function(e) { return $(e).text().substring(8) });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkQfL/1/)

Comment: Cause I changed it as new information became available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .each() function for this... Something like:

```
$(data).find('.tel a').each(function() {
    $(this).text(function(index,text) {
      return text+"substring(8)";
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can let jQuery do the work for you.

```
$(data).find('.tel a').addClass('substring');
```

jQuery will traverse the array of elements returned and add the class to all of them.

Comment: :) it's not a class ;)